# CSS3 background-clip

Tags: css

I'm using -webkit-background-clip to restrict a background image to the text in an h2 element.

My question is, does -moz-background-clip function the same way? This only seems to work in webkit browsers, which suggests it doesn't work yet in Firefox:

```
#header h1 a{
    background: url(img/logo-overlay.png) no-repeat #000;
    -moz-background-clip: text; -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent; -moz-text-fill-color: transparent; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Currently, in Firefox, the text is hidden (because of the color: transparent and text-fill-color: transparent properties) and only the background image and color are visible in the rectangular shape of the element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe `text` is a valid value for the `background-clip` property.

MDC states two different declaration, one for Firefox 3.6 and below, and the other for the upcoming Firefox 4. It also states the webkit equivalent.

```
Firefox (Gecko)     
1.0-3.6 (1.2-1.9.2)    -moz-background-clip:  padding | border
4.0 (2.0)              background-clip:     padding-box | border-box | content-box

Safari (WebKit)
3.0 (522)              -webkit-background-clip:  padding | border | content
```

See the MDC document here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip

As to what you're trying to achieve, I believe the `content-box` value is what you're looking for. Note that Firefox 3.6 and below do not appear to support this value.

See: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

Comment: Interesting. A value of 'text' in Webkit browsers was able to achieve this (zoomed in): http://cl.ly/2Ame. It must be completely proprietary to Webkit for now, then. Using content-box doesn't work - renders the exact same result as leaving out background-clip altogether. Is that supposed to behave differently? Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

`text` is now an experimental API for `background-clip` which get the background painted within the foreground text.

> Firefox, Chrome and Safari support the unofficial -webkit-background-clip: text (only with prefix)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip